# Firebase Crashlytics - failure during initialization on iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase in my Flutter application and I have a problem with `FirebaseCrashlytics` initialization on iOS devices.

I get the following error during launch:

```
10.16.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Failed to download settings. 
If this is your first time launching the app, make sure you have enabled Crashlytics in the Firebase Console. 
Error Domain=FIRCLSNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=404, type=2, request_id=, content_type=text/html; charset=utf-8}
```

Obviously, crash reports are not sent to the Crashlytic from iOS devices.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a problem with FirebaseCrashlytics settings fetching. To resolve:

1. **Enable Crashlytics**: Confirm Crashlytics is activated in the Firebase Console for your project.
2. **Bundle Identifier**: Check that the iOS bundle identifier matches the one in Firebase.
3. **GoogleService-Info.plist**: Ensure it's correctly placed in your app and includes Crashlytics settings.
4. **Update Firebase SDK**: Use the latest Firebase SDK. Update your Podfile and run `pod update`.
5. **Internet Permissions**: Make sure the app has internet access permissions in `Info.plist`.
6. **Clean Build**: Try a clean build: `flutter clean`, `cd ios`, `pod deintegrate`, `pod install`.
7. **Firebase Rules**: Check for any Firebase rules that might block connections.

If issues persist, contact Firebase support with the `request_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled crashlytics in FB console, and have followed the tutorial [to setup firebase with your app](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli).

Call `await Firebase.initializeApp();` at the startup up your app. According to docs you should [manually trigger a crash the first time you are using crashlytics](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage/) `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();`

Also,be sure you're importing the packages corretly.

```
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that firebase is connected to app correctly you can use `flutterfire`.

First, install firebase cli `npm install -g firebase-tools`.
Then, login `firebase login`.
And activate flutterfire in dart `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`.

Now in your project directory you can run `flutterfire configure`, follow further instructions from the command.

And for iOS it can also be a problem with iOS minimal version. Right now if you are using the latest X Code version - minimal iOS deployment target should be `12.0`.

Also, about failed settings download - you should try to use VPN, at least just to see if problem persists.